Is an Anti-neutron electric dipole moment also predicted by the standard model?
The neutron electric dipole moment is predicted by the standard model as follows (taken from Wikipedia and a paper [2]) :

As it is depicted above, in order to generate a nonzero nEDM one needs processes that violate CP symmetry. CP violation has been observed in weak interactions and is included in the Standard Model of particle physics via the CP-violating phase in the CKM matrix. However, the amount of CP violation is very small and therefore also the contribution to the nEDM: |dn| ~ 10−31 e⋅cm. [2]https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0008248

My question is, does the standard model also have a prediction for an anti neutron electric dipole moment, and could that be proven experimentally?

The standard model is CPT invariant, no?

I would think so, but all articles I point to don't have an answer to this.

Well, they don't because everybody accepts CPT and what holds for the neutron holds for its CPT conjugate, the antineutron. Your literature search is spotty.
